# User Control, can we add event in the property panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

After creating a User Control (using c# winforms), is it possible to create an event that can be accessed from the properties panel (during design time) like other default controls?

Comment: The only thing you could do wrong is not trying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  For example, within the class definition in the UserControl's .cs file, add the line:

```
public event EventHandler MyNewEvent;
```

At design time, in a form or control that contains an instance of your UserControl, you should be able to select the control and find the MyNewEvent entry in the properties panel.

Answer (score 0):

Add Browsable argument to your event definition:

```
[Browsable(true)]    
public event EventHandler MyNewEvent;
```